# Does there exist $\alpha>0, \beta\in (0,1)$ such that $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n}\le \alpha (a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n} + \beta \max_i(a_i)$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Let $a_1\ge a_2\ge \cdots\ge a_n\ge 0$ be given non-negative numbers. My question is the following:

> Is there any $\beta \in(0,1),\ \alpha>0$, such that $$\dfrac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\le \alpha (a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n}+\beta a_1?$$

This [article](https://rgmia.org/papers/v11e/RAM.pdf) derives inequalities of above sort, with $\alpha=1$ and $\beta =1/n$, but with $\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}|a_i-a_j|$ instead of $a_1$, multiplied with $\beta$. Also their method does not seem to be applicable to address my question. Is there any known result on this or is this an open question? Any ideas regarding how should one proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $\alpha=1/n,\beta=(n-1)/n$. Then $\alpha(a_1\dots a_n)^{1/n}\geq a_n,\beta a_1\geq (a_1+\dots+a_{n-1})/n$.

Comment: Oh right! That's such a simple observation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Wojowu: you probably mean $\alpha (a_1\ldots a_n)^{1/n} \ge a_n/n$.

Comment: @Henri Of course, silly typo.